# Create Sparse Matrix with Coordinate Storage System?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, sparse-matrix, colt

I am writing a java program which involves working with a 1058 X 1058 matrix containing float values. This matrix contains many zero values and so I need to store this as a sparse matrix and later use this matrix to generate a spanning tree. I checked many popular libraries like Colt, Jama, but somehow I am unable to put them to work with my code. I would like to have a coordinate storage system (similar to obtained in matlab using the sparse() function) like this:

```
(1055,1045)    1.0000
(1056,1045)    1.0000
(1057,1045)    1.0000
(1058,1045)    1.0000
(1047,1046)    1.0000
(1048,1046)    1.0000
(1049,1046)    1.0000
(1050,1046)    1.0000
(1051,1046)    1.0000
(1052,1046)    1.0000
(1053,1046)    1.0000
(1054,1046)    1.0000
(1055,1046)    1.0000
```

Can anyone suggest how to go about this?

Comment: _" I checked many popular libraries like Colt, Jama, but somehow I am unable to put them to work with my code."_ If you give more detail about the problems you had with those libraries, we could help you get them working.

Comment: I am trying to use the methods of the class SparseDoubleMatrix2D (http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/impl/SparseDoubleMatrix2D.html#assign(cern.colt.matrix.DoubleMatrix2D). But I am not able to generate the coordinate storage wise output using the methods listed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it quickly without any lib. Create the following class :

```
MatrixIndex implements Comparable<MatrixIndex>
{
  private final int _x;
  private final int _y;

  ...
}
```

Then use it in some :

```
TreeMap<MatrixIndex,Double>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read more on comparator and TreeMap and have got an idea of how to implement it. But, as for the class MatrixIndex, is a comparator required in this case? As far as I understand, TreeMap gives returns data in sorted manner and since my return value will be coordinates and value, which are numbers so they will be already sorted. If I use a comparator as you suggested, how should I get the float[][] matrix values into this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to get the desired output using TreeMap. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java) library that handles this with `CRSMatrix`/`CCSMatrix` sparse matrix types and `MatrixMarketStream` class. Here is the brief example:

Source file "matrix.mm" (5x5 matrix with 8 non-zero elements):

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real general
5  5  8
1     1   1.000e+00
2     2   1.050e+01
3     3   1.500e-02
1     4   6.000e+00
4     2   2.505e+02
4     4  -2.800e+02
4     5   3.332e+01
5     5   1.200e+01
```

Java source (la4j usage):

```
Matrix a = new CRSMatrix(Matrices.asMatrixMarketSource(
                           new FileInputStream(new File("matrix.mm"))));

System.out.println("DET(A) = " + a.determinant());
```

About the MatrixMarket format read [here](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html). About CRS/CCS formats read [here](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node373.html) and [here](http://netlib.org/utk/papers/templates/node91.html).

To generate MatrixMarket output use following code:

```
Matrix a = new CRSMatrix(...);
MatrixStream out = new MatrixMarketStream(new FileOutputStream(
                        new File("matrix.mm")));

out.writeMatrix(a);
```